# pdf and djvu: Raster or vector graphic image

Tags: images, pdf, djvu

1. I was wondering as image formats,
   what pdf (eps, ps) and djvu are
   classified into, raster image,
   vector graphic image?
2. I think pdf (eps, ps) and djvu can
   all contain both raster image and
   vector graphic image, so are they
   hybrid image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF's are largely comprised of vector elements and AI treats them as vector (e.g., you can open/edit/save).  Yes, they can contain raster elements, but it treats them as vectors and attempts to scale them as it does embedded fonts and illustrations.  Call it a hybrid if you will, but the raster support is more a concession than original intent.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with `djvu`, but from the wikipedia page, it sounds like a `pdf` alternative, so the same vector-style scaling should apply.